# How to apply a function to a pandas dataframe column containing strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I open a CSV file which has a country column.

I want to create a new column which has that countries ISO3 Code.

I can do this by installing

```
import country_converter as coco
```

It works in the following way:

```
coco.convert('Afghanistan')
```

returns

```
AFG
```

I now want to create a new column and apply that function to all my countries to get corresponding ISO3 codes.

I tried to do this in the following way:

```
df['CODE'] = coco.convert(df['Country'])
```

All this does is convert the first country code which is AFG and adds it to all the countries.

Example:

```
           Country        Date  Value CODE
0      Afghanistan  2020-03-12      7  AFG
1      Afghanistan  2020-03-11      7  AFG
2      Afghanistan  2020-03-10      5  AFG
3      Afghanistan  2020-03-09      4  AFG
4      Afghanistan  2020-03-08      4  AFG
5      Afghanistan  2020-03-07      1  AFG
6      Afghanistan  2020-03-06      1  AFG
7      Afghanistan  2020-03-05      1  AFG
8      Afghanistan  2020-03-04      1  AFG
9      Afghanistan  2020-03-03      1  AFG
10     Afghanistan  2020-03-02      1  AFG
11     Afghanistan  2020-03-01      1  AFG
12     Afghanistan  2020-02-29      1  AFG
13     Afghanistan  2020-02-28      1  AFG
14     Afghanistan  2020-02-27      1  AFG
15     Afghanistan  2020-02-26      1  AFG
16     Afghanistan  2020-02-25      1  AFG
17     Afghanistan  2020-02-24      1  AFG
18     Afghanistan  2020-02-23      0  AFG
19     Afghanistan  2020-02-22      0  AFG
20     Afghanistan  2020-02-21      0  AFG
21     Afghanistan  2020-02-20      0  AFG
22     Afghanistan  2020-02-19      0  AFG
23     Afghanistan  2020-02-18      0  AFG
24     Afghanistan  2020-02-17      0  AFG
25     Afghanistan  2020-02-16      0  AFG
26     Afghanistan  2020-02-15      0  AFG
27     Afghanistan  2020-02-14      0  AFG
28     Afghanistan  2020-02-13      0  AFG
29     Afghanistan  2020-02-12      0  AFG
...            ...         ...    ...  ...
20676      Vietnam  2020-02-20     16  AFG
20677      Vietnam  2020-02-19     16  AFG
20678      Vietnam  2020-02-18     16  AFG
20679      Vietnam  2020-02-17     16  AFG
20680      Vietnam  2020-02-16     16  AFG
20681      Vietnam  2020-02-15     16  AFG
20682      Vietnam  2020-02-14     16  AFG
20683      Vietnam  2020-02-13     16  AFG
20684      Vietnam  2020-02-12     15  AFG
20685      Vietnam  2020-02-11     15  AFG
20686      Vietnam  2020-02-10     14  AFG
20687      Vietnam  2020-02-09     13  AFG
20688      Vietnam  2020-02-08     13  AFG
20689      Vietnam  2020-02-07     10  AFG
20690      Vietnam  2020-02-06     10  AFG
20691      Vietnam  2020-02-05      8  AFG
20692      Vietnam  2020-02-04      8  AFG
20693      Vietnam  2020-02-03      8  AFG
20694      Vietnam  2020-02-02      6  AFG
20695      Vietnam  2020-02-01      6  AFG
20696      Vietnam  2020-01-31      2  AFG
20697      Vietnam  2020-01-30      2  AFG
20698      Vietnam  2020-01-29      2  AFG
20699      Vietnam  2020-01-28      2  AFG
20700      Vietnam  2020-01-27      2  AFG
20701      Vietnam  2020-01-26      2  AFG
20702      Vietnam  2020-01-25      2  AFG
20703      Vietnam  2020-01-24      2  AFG
20704      Vietnam  2020-01-23      2  AFG
20705      Vietnam  2020-01-22      0  AFG
```

[20706 rows x 4 columns]

I also tried:

```
df['CODE'] = df['Country'].apply(coco.convert)
```

But this just shuts down my kernel.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for apply function per groups by `Country`, idea is run function only once per group for improve speed:

```
df['CODE'] = df.groupby('Country')['Country'].transform(coco.convert)
```

Also your solution with `apply` working for me, only slow:

```
df['CODE'] = df['Country'].apply(coco.convert)
```

**Performance**:

```
In [19]: %timeit df.groupby('Country')['Country'].transform(coco.convert)
60.2 ms ± 4.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit df['Country'].apply(coco.convert)
1.2 s ± 6.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what specific errors did i make in my code/thinking?

Comment: @osyysoosyyso - I think `df['CODE'] = df['Country'].apply(coco.convert)` is correct way, not sure why failed for you. My code working? Because here should function run only once per group.

Comment: How could you do the opposite? i.e. from from code to country?